# How Data Manipulation done in Hadoop Cluster?

Tags: hadoop, cluster-computing, hdfs, data-manipulation

How to read and write files in [Hadoop Cluster](http://guruzon.com/6/hadoop-cluster):
what are the file read and file write operations and HDFS commands for that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Have you tried anything to find it out?

Answer (score 0):

use hadoop  command.

```
hadoop dfs  -copyToLocal [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> <localdst>
this commads write the file to local machine

hadoop dfs -copyFromLocal <local-file-path> <Hdfs-location>
this command write file into hdfs
```

for more command just write

```
hadoop dfs -help

hadoop fs is the command to execute fs commands. The full syntax is: 

hadoop fs [-fs <local | file system URI>] [-conf <configuration file>]
[-D <property=value>] [-ls <path>] [-lsr <path>] [-du <path>]
[-dus <path>] [-mv <src> <dst>] [-cp <src> <dst>] [-rm [-skipTrash] <src>]
[-rmr [-skipTrash] <src>] [-put <localsrc> ... <dst>] [-copyFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>]
[-moveFromLocal <localsrc> ... <dst>] [-get [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> <localdst>
[-getmerge <src> <localdst> [addnl]] [-cat <src>]
[-copyToLocal [-ignoreCrc] [-crc] <src> <localdst>] [-moveToLocal <src> <localdst>]
[-mkdir <path>] [-report] [-setrep [-R] [-w] <rep> <path/file>]
[-touchz <path>] [-test -[ezd] <path>] [-stat [format] <path>]
[-tail [-f] <path>] [-text <path>]
[-chmod [-R] <MODE[,MODE]... | OCTALMODE> PATH...]
[-chown [-R] [OWNER][:[GROUP]] PATH...]
[-chgrp [-R] GROUP PATH...]
[-count[-q] <path>]
[-help [cmd]]
```